# OpenLayers 4 center map on city coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers, center

I have a problem with centering my map on creation.

My javascript code is from the quick start guide, same goes for the html code.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([51.35847, 7.49918], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
```

It just won't center and I don't understand why? I did exactly as described in other questions and topics on stackoverflow....

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gpo33ga6/

Comment: What are you trying to center

Comment: The map itself on a city with the given coordinates

Comment: Which city is it?

Comment: I got the coordinates from OSM / Google Maps, it's Hagen, NRW, Germany

Comment: increase zoom , or are you trying to show icon ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.49918, 51.35847]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
```

Take care that the function takes `(Lon, Lat)` and not `(Lat, Lon)`.

Comment: No problem, it is the purpose.